# Magento2 related products widget JS not triggering?

Tags: magento2, related-products, pdp

Actually using Ajax concept fetching related products & displaying in the form of HTML but i have been facing a problem i.e there is a JS attribute for an element  `data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}'`  which is not triggering.

> app/design/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider/templates/product/list/items.phtml

Here is the template file from code share: https://codeshare.io/aYoM4R

**app/code/Demo/ConfigurableSku/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
   config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
             'Demo_ConfigurableSku/js/model/skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Demo/ConfigurableSku/view/frontend/web/js/model/skuswitch.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
    return function(targetModule){
        
        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        targetModule.prototype.configurableSku = $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html();
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
            var simpleSku = this.configurableSku;
            if(this.simpleProduct){

                simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct]; 
                //Added Logic For Related products
                //simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];
                var simplePid = this.options.spConfig.simpleid[this.simpleProduct];
                var configPid = this.options.spConfig.productId;
                var ajaxUrl = this.options.spConfig.ajaxUrl;
                $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: ajaxUrl,
                    data: {product_sku : simpleSku, parentflag : 0},
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(typeof response != 'undefined') {
                            $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html('');
                            $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html(response.message);
                            $('#datarelated-'+configPid).find('#pre-div').css('display','none');
                        } 
                    },error: function(response) {
                        console.log("something went wrong while selecting simple " + response.message);
                    }
                });

            }else{
                //first load
                // added logic for related products
                var configPid = this.options.spConfig.productId;
                var ajaxUrl = this.options.spConfig.ajaxUrl;
                $.ajax({
                    showLoader: true,
                    url: ajaxUrl,
                    data: {product_id:configPid,parentflag:1},
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(typeof response != 'undefined') {
                            $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html('');
                            $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html(response.message);
                            $('#datarelated-'+configPid).find('#pre-div').css('display','none');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        console.log("something went wrong with configurable " + response.message);
                    }
                });
            }
            
            $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);      
            return original();
        });

        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

> **related-products.js:**
> pub/static/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/en_US/Magento_Catalog/js/related-products.js

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.relatedProducts', {
        options: {
            relatedCheckbox: '.related-checkbox', // Class name for a related product's input checkbox.
            relatedProductsCheckFlag: false, // Related products checkboxes are initially unchecked.
            relatedProductsField: '#related-products-field', // Hidden input field that stores related products.
            selectAllMessage: $.mage.__('select all'),
            unselectAllMessage: $.mage.__('unselect all'),
            selectAllLink: '[role="select-all"]',
            //selectAllLink : '#selectdata',
            elementsSelector: '.item.product'
        },

        /**
         * Bind events to the appropriate handlers.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {

            $(this.options.selectAllLink).on('click', $.proxy(this._selectAllRelated, this));
            $(this.options.relatedCheckbox).on('click', $.proxy(this._addRelatedToProduct, this));
             this._showRelatedProducts(
                this.element.find(this.options.elementsSelector),
                this.element.data('limit'),
                this.element.data('shuffle')
            );
        },

        /**
         * This method either checks all checkboxes for a product's set of related products (select all)
         * or unchecks them (unselect all).
         * @private
         * @param {jQuery.Event} e - Click event on either the "select all" link or the "unselect all" link.
         * @return {Boolean} - Prevent default event action and event propagation.
         */
        _selectAllRelated: function (e) {
            console.log("_selectAllRelated calling"); 
            var innerHTML = this.options.relatedProductsCheckFlag ?
                this.options.selectAllMessage : this.options.unselectAllMessage;

            $(e.target).html(innerHTML);
            $(this.options.relatedCheckbox).attr(
                'checked',
                this.options.relatedProductsCheckFlag = !this.options.relatedProductsCheckFlag
            );
            this._addRelatedToProduct();

            return false;
        },

        /**
         * This method iterates through each checkbox for all related products and collects only those products
         * whose checkbox has been checked. The selected related products are stored in a hidden input field.
         * @private
         */
        _addRelatedToProduct: function () {
            console.log("_addRelatedToProductcalling"); 
            console.log("_addRelatedToProduct");
            $(this.options.relatedProductsField).val(
                $(this.options.relatedCheckbox + ':checked').map(function () {
                    return this.value;
                }).get().join(',')
            );
        },

        /**
         * Show related products according to limit. Shuffle if needed.
         * @param {*} elements
         * @param {*} limit
         * @param {*} shuffle
         * @private
         */
        _showRelatedProducts: function (elements, limit, shuffle) {
            var index;

            if (shuffle) {
                this._shuffle(elements);
            }

            if (limit === 0) {
                limit = elements.length;
            }

            for (index = 0; index < limit; index++) {
                $(elements[index]).show();
            }
        },

        /* jscs:disable */
        /* eslint-disable */
        /**
         * Shuffle an array
         * @param {Array} o
         * @returns {*}
         */
        _shuffle: function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
            for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
            return o;
        }

        /* jscs:disable */
        /* eslint:disable */
    });

    return $.mage.relatedProducts;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the below reference and its working my functionality. Here I am posting answer for others those who are face same kind of issue further it will help.

> $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html(response.message).trigger('contentUpdated');

```
 $.ajax({
 showLoader: true,
 url: ajaxUrl,
 data: {product_sku : simpleSku, parentflag : 0},
 type: "POST",
 cache: false,
 success: function(response) {
 if(typeof response != 'undefined') {
   $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html('');
   $('.columns').find('#datarelated-'+configPid).html(response.message).trigger('contentUpdated');
   $('#datarelated-'+configPid).find('#pre-div').css('display','none');
 }
},error: function(response) {
   console.log("something went wrong while selecting simple " + response.message);
}
  });
```

**Reference:** https://gist.github.com/timneutkens/004f8ac0f963068fa718e8397877194e